# printing table of rows specified by another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to output the lines of a file where the first column's values match the firsts column's values of the second using awk. Easier explained with an example:

```
file1.txt
1
2
3
4
5

file2.txt
1   dog
4   fish
6   cat
9   rabbit
```

I want file3.txt to be:

```
1   dog
4   fish
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `join` command:

```
$ join file{1,2}.txt
```

Or use `awk`

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{dict[$1]; next}; $1 in dict' file{1,2}.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]; next}; $1 in arr' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```